# Who would I take my knives to, to be conditioned?

Tags: cleaning, knives, sharpening

I would like my knives all to be sharpened by a professional.  Some knives I cannot sharpen because they have an intricate serrated edge that I would ruin if I used my own stone.

Several of my knives also have stains, whether they be rust stains or some other kind of mottling.

I figure maybe I would go to a key maker.  Not sure if there is someone else who specializes in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the US, there are business called "sharpening services" that are dedicated to sharpening knives, saws, lawnmower blades, and other tools. You can probably find one in your area by searching google or yelp.